# How can i update several datasets with mutate?

Tags: r

I have a datasets with names in the format df_1, df_2, df_3,... 
and i want to change the column x of these dataframes, i tried to do it in some ways and it didn't work, below is one of them:

```
dfs <- ls(pattern = "df")
    for(i in 1:(length(dfs))){
      eval(parse(text = (dfs[i]))) <- eval(parse(text = dfs[i])) %>% mutate(x = str_pad(x, width = 8, pad = "0")
    }
```

It returns the following error:

```
Error in file(filename, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r") :
cannot open file 'df_1': No such file or directory
```

I also tried creating a list with the dataframes and iterating over it, but it didn't work either.

Any suggestions for an easy way to do it?

Comment: Try `mget(ls(pattern = "^df_\\d+")) %>% map(~ .x %>% mutate(x = str_pad(x, width = 8, pad = "0")))`

Comment: Yikes. How did you wind up with all these sequentially numbered data frames? What ever process you used to generate them probably should have added them to a list them you could have just applied mutate operations over that list. You should not regularly be using `eval()`, `parse()`, `get()` or `assign()`.

Comment: @MrFlick I somone passed the data frames to me like this! I kept wondering why while dealing with it! And i'm aware i should not regularly be using those functions, thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all the datasets into `list` with `mget`, then loop through the `list` with `map` and `mutate` the 'x' column in the `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "^df_\\d+")) %>%
           map(~ .x %>% 
              mutate(x = str_pad(x, width = 8, pad = "0")))
```